# How do I change http cache control options when a page contains personalized components?

Tags: sxa, personalization, caching

I am using Sitecore 9.3, SXA. I want to change the HTTP Header `cache-control` to `no-store` when a page or item on that page has been personalized. How do I go about doing this? Any articles/blogs or advice would be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

I do not believe that caching based on personalized data is built in by default but we did something like this on an earlier version of sitecore, not using sxa. Based on the [caching documentation](https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/sxa/93/sitecore-experience-accelerator/en/set-sxa-caching-options.html#UUID-9b2f7244-b427-5df3-596f-c130789163c9_id__Global_caching_options), I am assuming you can do the same thing in 9.3. Here is a nice [blog post](http://www.sitecorecoding.com/2016/02/caching-rendering-html-when-conditional.html) that should give you an idea of how to achieve what you are looking for.